# Inquire in fortran 90

Tags: bash, unix, fortran, fortran90

I have the statement:

```
Inquire( FILE = "myfile.dat", EXIST = existence )
```

My question is where does the function inquire() look for this file? Does it look first in the present working directory and if the file is not there, where else does inquire() look? Does it look in my bash $PATHs?

/M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `INQUIRE` is not a function, it is a statement.

Fortran standard doesn't have any notion of directories, so it depends on the operating system and the compiler, where it has access to. In practice it looks in the current directory. You can also use absolute path, of course.

Comment: Ok! Thanks. I'll just link the file to the working directory.